# Issues in Configuring the database

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I am editing the `backends/settings.py` file to configure the database

```
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

It gives the following error

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [MySQLdb module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/databases/#mysqldb) separately; it doesn't come with the Django distribution itself.

Like Django, it is [available on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python), so you can install it with `easy_install MySQL-python` or `pip install MySQL-python`.

Comment: Can you pls tell me the location where i have to place the setup of mysql-python so that i can install it from terminal

Comment: @neeraj: You install it in the same way you installed Django.

Comment: @neeraj: without more detail I can't help you there. Post a new question with details on how you installed MySQL-python and Django and explain how you cannot seem to import the MySQLdb module.

Answer (score 0):

Neeraj i am not able to comment on above answer so i am writing here

as Martijn said

install mysql-python using  `easy_install MySQL-python`

restart your server  manually using  python manage.py runserver